# pandas describe() not showing

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I am following the Google course on machine learning and trying to make it work on Atom instead of simply using the colab version. Model training and other stuff went well but I am having problems using the describe() function. I have consulted the documentation but still couldn't make the summary to show. It only worked when I tried interactive python on the command line. Relevant parts of my code are as below. Thank you for your help.

```py
import math

from IPython import display
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import gridspec
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import metrics
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.data import Dataset

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
pd.options.display.max_rows = 10
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.lf}'.format

# Load data set
california_housing_dataframe = pd.read_csv("https://storage.googleapis.com/mledu-datasets/california_housing_train.csv", sep=",")

......

# Split the data set into training sets of the first 12000/17000 examples,
training_examples = preprocess_features(california_housing_dataframe.head(12000))
training_targets = preprocess_targets(california_housing_dataframe.head(12000))

# and validation sets of the last 5000/17000 examples.
validation_examples = preprocess_features(california_housing_dataframe.tail(5000))
validation_targets = preprocess_targets(california_housing_dataframe.tail(5000))

# Double-check that the splitting is correct. (NOT WORKING YET)
print("Training examples summary:")
training_examples.describe()
```

after running the code, my terminal simply ignores the lines with describe() and prints out

```
Training examples summary: 
Validation examples summary: 
Training targets summary: 
Validation targets summary:
```

and then carries on training the model.

Comment: What is the traceback error that appears?

Comment: my terminal simply ignored the lines with describe() and printed out 
```
Training examples summary:
Validation examples summary:
Training targets summary:
Validation targets summary:
```
and then carries on training the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the stack traceback, my guess is that a typo at

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.lf}'.format
```

is messing with your data intake. That **letter** `l` should be a **number** `1`. You are telling the formatter how many digits of floating point precision you want printed. Correct syntax is

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.1f}'.format
```

Comment: oh right!! Thank you for spotting that! Though the `training_examples.describe()` still didn't work, I tried `display.display(training_examples.describe())` and it worked after I also corrected the typo! Thanks again.

Comment: still, why can't I simply call `describe()`?

Comment: I am having no problem with describe function. I'm using ipython3 and training_examples.describe() is showing the expected results. What is `display.display` function exactly? Where are you executing the code?

Comment: I'm running my script from a terminal in Atom on Mac. Could you recommend an alternative where I can try out my code? I believe `display.display` is an IPython function that displays Python object in frontends.

Comment: I have tried with Atom on Windows and same behavior occurs. It seems that Atom script package is somehow running IPython as interpreter. I usually code in Sublime and this does not happen, as I am able to choose the build system. I don't know if and where you could configure that on Atom. My guess is that running the script directly from terminal would solve this issue, but I don't have access to a Mac to check it.

Comment: I have just ran the script directly from a terminal yet somehow `training_examples.describe()` still doesn't work. I guess it has to do with the rest of the code? Because according to the solution code on Google Crash Course, `display.display` is used in lieu of just `describe()` However, running directly from the terminal did solve another problem where the plot I created with matplotlib also failed to show up when I run Atom terminal.

Comment: have you tried `california_housing_dataframe.describe()` right after the csv dataset is loaded? Just to make sure data isn't being lost somewhere after in the workflow

Comment: yes it works! I guess there must be sth wrong in the workflow. I will try to trace the entire code again. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 18):

I'm also doing the Google's ML course and ran into the same problem where the describe function does not print to my output window. What worked for me was wrapping describe() in a print() function like below.

> print(california_housing_dataframe.describe())

That produced the descriptive stats in my output window.

Disclaimer: I'm running my python programs from Sublime, and not Atom, and I'm using the following packages below:

- Sublime Text 3
- pandas           0.23.0
- tensorflow-gpu   1.8.0
- CUDA             9.0.176.2
- cudnn            7.1

Hope this helps!

Comment: This fixed my issues not seeing data in visual studio. thanks.